# Deploying Django with uwsgi and nginx, uwsgi ok but nginx not working

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to run my site, when i run

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8080 --protocol=http --chdir /opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/ --wsgi-file /opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/landivarpj/wsgi.py
```

i can access 192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 fine and my test text appears,
but if i try to go trought 192.xxx.xxx.xxx i only get an nginx welcome page,
and if i try to go in trought my domain www.xxxxxxxx.com, then it doesnt work at all.

in my project folder(opt/virtualenv/landivarpj) i have a uswgi_params file with

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

then in (opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/landivarpj) the wsgi.py is

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "landivarpj.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

in etc/nginx/sites-available is have drlandivar.conf

```
upstream django {
    server 192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name drlandivar.com www.drlandivar.com;
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location /media  {
        alias /opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/media;  
    }

    location /static {
        alias /opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/static; 
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/uwsgi_params; 
    }
}
```

the site-available and site-enable are linked

what have i done wrong why it work on 192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080
but not trought the domain and nginx

***** new edit as recommended on nginx/availables-site/drlandivar.conf

```
upstream django {
    server 192.254.145.207:8080;
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name drlandivar.com www.drlandivar.com;
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location /media  {
        alias /opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/media;  
    }

    location /static {
        alias /opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/static; 
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://django;
    }
}
```

it still give me same problem page only load trought 192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 not trought drlandivar.com
please help

Comment: `server_name drlandivar.com www.drlandivar.com;` means that the block does not accept requests without a host name (just an ip address). So nginx displays the fallback page instead. Note that when DEBUG=False, Django should also reject requests without an accepted host name. So naked ip-address urls would typically fail in any case.

Comment: Do you intent to serve your django page in production just using the ip-address? That's possible, but then you should reformulate your question to ask specifically about that.

Comment: You are using uwsgi with HTTP protocol, so you have to use proxy_pass (instead of uwsgi_pass) in your nginx config. (or vice versa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing yours to a working example of mine, one thing stands out. Try

```
...
location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    proxy_pass http://django;
}
```

Adding `--logto /var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi.log` to your uwsgi invocation (after creating `/var/log/uswgi` and making it writeable to the uwsgi process) might shed some additional light.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `proxy_pass` instead. The following configuration should do the trick.

```
upstream django {
    server 192.254.145.207:8080;
}

server {

    ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://django;
    }
}
```

Comment: that doesnt do the trick, or im doing something wrong, i edited the code see ****section above. but the page only open with 192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080, cant load it with drlandivar.com :(

Comment: could you check nginx's & django's log? is it 5xx error?

Comment: im sorry i am a huuuuge newb in this i wouldnt know where to check

Comment: For nginx, `/var/log/nginx/access.log` & `/var/log/nginx/error.log` are default settings. For django, you still run from command, right? Then please check if there is anything hit django at all?

Comment: list is loong for nginx,but in access.log all i see are 404 errors

Comment: ok, I would do this. `sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log` Then you hit www.drlandivar.com; it should show up here. If not try again or better yet tail both access & error log at the same time.

Comment: trying to load www.drlandivar.com just give me Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2018:14:18:55 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3698 "-" "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2018:14:20:02 -0500] "GET /whm-server-status HTTP/1.0" 404 3652 "-" "-"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182445/discussion-between-sipp11-and-mariepiercm).